# Macros in Cocos2d-x project

Tags: android, ios, macros, cocos2d-x

When developing soley for iOS I define macros in `Macros.h` and `#import` this file in `Prefix.pch`. This way I don't need to `#import` the macros file all over the place.

This doesn't work when targeting both iOS and Android in a Cocos2d-x project. I've tried importing the macros file both inside and outside the Objective-C guard in prefix.pch. I even tried including the macros file in cocos2d.h. All of these build in Xcode but none build in Eclipse.

**How can I define macros in a Cocos2d-x project for both iOS and Android such that I can include/import that file once and give the macros global scope?**

Comment: check if eclipse is capable and set up to use the precompiled header, that's where i would start looking

Comment: @SundayMonday, did you find any solution? I also have the same problem.

Comment: @Khawar Currently I'm just including the file when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

I define macros in `Defines.h` (`Macros.h` in your case) then in `Prefix.pch`
I'll add something like this

```
.#ifdef __cplusplus
.#include "Defines.h"
.#endif
```

(ignore the dot in front of #)